# Google Page Rank. Struggling with my code

Tags: javascript, php

I've been searching all over, and based on what I've read google discontinued the Page Rank, and the only way to check this is by google search.

Is there any solution to get Page Rank?

**This is what I've tried**

```
function check($page){
```

// Open a socket to the toolbarqueries address, used by Google Toolbar
    $socket = fsockopen("toolbarqueries.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

`// If a connection can be established
if($socket) {
  // Prep socket headers
  $out = "GET /tbr?client=navclient-auto&ch=".$this->checkHash($this->createHash($page)).
          "&features=Rank&q=info:".$page."&num=100&filter=0 HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  $out .= "Host: toolbarqueries.google.com\r\n";
  $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; GoogleToolbar 2.0.114-big; Windows XP 5.1)\r\n";
  $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

  // Write settings to the socket
  fwrite($socket, $out);

  // When a response is received...
  $result = "";
  while(!feof($socket)) {
    $data = fgets($socket, 128);
    $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
    if($pos !== false){
      $pagerank = substr($data, $pos + 9);
      $result += $pagerank;
    }
  }
  // Close the connection
  fclose($socket);

  // Return the rank!
  return $result;
}`

Comment: Is this question anyhow related to gwt or google-app engine? Looks like you are just consuming an api from google.

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt - The Question is related to page Rank.. Any how you can help me on this please...